How can I resolve Angular CORS Policy errors when trying to post data to an API?
I am trying to post a form data to an API from an angular application running on localhost, and my code is as follows:
submitdata(){
  this.http.post(this.url, this.fg.value, {observe: 'body'} ).subscribe((response: any)=>{
    console.log(response.body)
  })
}

but every time I send the data to the API which is also running on my local computer, the browser gives me the following errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/home' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, data, http, https, isolated-app.

On the API endpoint I installed cors to an express node.js server and set the origin to http://localhost:4200 but still the errors persist.
I tried different CORS policy configurationn in the express server and even allowed all origins to connect to the API but to no avail, like this:
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:4200"
    
}))

when it didn't work I tried setting the response header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin to true but that too didn't solve the problem.
and finally I got frustrated  and I shutdown the server and to see what the error will be and that's when I found out that the request is not even reaching the server and Angular keeps telling me the request is blocked by CORS policy.
I am feeling like the problem is from angular httpClient I use to make the request to the API, but in any case what am I missing please?

What does this.url contain? Looks like it contains localhost:5000. Try http://localhost:5000 instead.

JSON Derulo might be right, but in order to find out for sure, you can open the browser's console and go to the Network tab to see the actual request being sent.

This question is similar to: origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy in Angular7. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try the below code in your node.js server. Put the code at the top of other middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
 });

